# Linking to another package - undefined symbol

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to use c++ classes from the package `rlas` (on CRAN). I wrote the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <rlasstreamer.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(rlas)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void f(CharacterVector file)
{
  RLASstreamer lasstreamer(file);
  return;
}
```

Also I added `LinkingTo: Rcpp,rlas` in `DESCRIPTION`. The package compiles, so the header is found but the library is not linked:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN12RLASstreamerD1Ev
```

The linkage command looks like that with nothing related to `rlas`

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o pkgname.so function_f.o RcppExports.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

As a solution I cheated by creating a `Makevars` with an hard coded path to the library which is in my `home/`.

```
PKG_LIBS= /home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rlas/libs/rlas.so
```

And it works!

I believed that it was the job of the `Rcpp::depends` tags. What did I missed to link properly another R package? May it comes from the `rlas` package that could be ill-formed?

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that you can just access the shared library of another R package. You cannot.

Comment: And what is the solution? I mean, we can depend on Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppProgress and many other one. So `rlas` is ill-formed with respect of linkage capabilities? (`rlas` is mine btw). `rlas` should be header only?

Comment: Header-only interfaces works (easiest).  Next is explicit exporting of individual function (look eg at my packages RApiSerialize exporting RcppRedis using).  All that is documented.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the header only option is the best. I don't understand from your packages how to export a class (if it is possible)

Comment: Well actually I cannot make a header only library there is too much code to change. Is that possible to export a class? Not only functions.

Comment: You cannot export a _class_ as the interface has to be in C, and C has no classes.  I looked at `rlas` -- it is just a handful of functions. You can easily export those, following `RApiDatetime` or `RApiSerialize` or one of the other packages doing that -- and you *know* it will work *reliably* and *cross-platform*.  Don't hack it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a hard coded path in `Makevars` you could create a suitable entry dynamically during `configure`. Here some R code that can be used to find the location of the library:

```
libs.dir <- system.file( "libs", package = "rlas")
paste0(libs.dir, .Platform$file.sep, "rlas", .Platform$dynlib.ext)
```

You could even add that to the `rlas` together with a  `rlas.package.skeleton` function. See for example my RcppArrayFire package:

- https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/blob/master/inst/skeleton/configure
- https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/blob/master/R/flags.R.in

Edit: Here a worked out example:

Create a package skeleton an change to the directory

```
$ Rscript -e "Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()"
$ cd anRpackage
```

Create or update some files:

```
$ cat configure
#!/bin/sh
RLAS_LIBS=`Rscript -e "cat(system.file('libs', 'rlas.so', package = 'rlas'))"`
sed -e "s|@RLAS_LIBS@|${RLAS_LIBS}|" src/Makevars.in > src/Makevars

$ cat cleanup
#!/bin/sh
rm -f src/Makevars src/*.o src/*.so

$ cat src/Makevars.in 
PKG_LIBS = @RLAS_LIBS@

$ cat src/rcpp_hello_world.cpp 
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <rlasstreamer.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void rcpp_hello_world() {
  RLASstreamer lasstreamer("foo");
  return;
}

$ grep rlas DESCRIPTION
LinkingTo: Rcpp, rlas
```

Compile Rcpp attributes:

```
$ Rscript -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes()"
```

Build, check and install the package:

```
$ R CMD build .
[...]
$ R CMD check anRpackage_1.0.tar.gz 
[...]
$ R CMD INSTALL anRpackage_1.0.tar.gz 
[...]
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o anRpackage.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rlas/libs/rlas.so -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
[...]
```

Here the command line from the linker is of interest. It shows that `rlas.so` is included with full path. Now try the package:

```
$ Rscript -e "anRpackage::rcpp_hello_world()"
ERROR: cannot open file 'foo'
ERROR: cannot open lasreadertxt with file name 'foo'
Fehler in anRpackage::rcpp_hello_world() : 
  LASlib internal error. See message above.
Execution halted
```

So while we get an error, this is an error from LASlib, which is contained in `rlas.so`. If we look at the output from `ldd` we see again `rlas.so` included with full path, which is different from the other linked libraries:

```
$ ldd ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/anRpackage/libs/anRpackage.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4c79d000)
    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rlas/libs/rlas.so (0x00007fede63fc000)
    libR.so => /usr/lib/libR.so (0x00007fede5d7a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fede59f8000)
[...]
```

Comment: That seems interesting. However `configure` is something I don't mastered at all. I'm keen to learn but could you develop more your answer to help me to get started with this new thing.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this will not work.  R loads one and exactly one dynamic library, named the same name as the package, from the libs directory. And libraries the system linker can use start with `lib*` which our per-package files do not.

Comment: I have added a worked example. @JRR please let me know if this makes my idea clearer

Comment: I have added a worked example, @Dirk please let me know when this will break ;-)

Comment: @RalfStubner It is almost what I did. I was so close! It works but... have you ever released a pkg with such "trick". Does it pass CRAN checks? Especially on Windows?

Comment: @JRR I have only used this for internal packages and I have not tried in on Windows. It might work if you use `.Platform$dynlib.ext` instead of `.so`.

Comment: @RalfStubner as expect by Dirk is does not compile on CRAN.

Comment: @JRR To bad. So this is for local packages only. Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: `undefined reference to `RLASstreamer::~RLASstreamer()' . The key is that the CRAN removed or did not consuder the `PKG_LIBS` statement we enforced (I made a `Makevars.win`) and this the lib is not linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171388/discussion-between-ralf-stubner-and-jrr).